# Extjs 5.1.2 Listeners on a dynamically generated element

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am creating a page which will dynamically generate collapsed panels.  When a user expands these panels, it will perform a GET request and populate this generated panel with the JSON response.  The idea is to perform a sort of lazy-load or as-needed load, as the amount of data that would be shown initially can get overwhelming.

However, I can't seem to get the listeners for my panels to work.

Here is the code, which generates the panels through a button's click function:

```
          xtype : 'button',
          listeners : {
            click : function (button, e, eOpts) {
              console.log("Click function");
              Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'data/Countries.json',
                success: function(response, options) {
                  var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).results;
                  var container = Ext.getCmp('panelContainer');
                  container.removeAll();
                  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                  {
                    container.add({
                      xtype: 'panel',
                      title: 'Country Name - ' + data[i].countryName,
                      collapsible: true,
                      listeners: {
                        expand: function() {
                          Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'data/CountryData.json',
                            success: function(response, options) {
                              var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).results;
                              var me = this;
                              me.add({
                                xtype: 'grid', 
                                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
                                  {
                                      fields : [{
                                        name: 'gdp'
                                      }, {
                                        name: 'rank'
                                      }, {
                                        name: 'founded'
                                      }, {
                                        name: 'governor'
                                      }, {
                                        name: 'notes'
                                      }], //eo fields
                                    data: data.information,
                                  }),// eo store
                                columns: [
                                  { text: 'GDP',  dataIndex: 'gdp'},
                                  { text: 'rank', dataIndex: 'rank'},
                                  { text: 'Date', dataIndex: 'founded'},
                                  { text: 'name', dataIndex: 'governor'},
                                  { text: 'Notes', dataIndex: 'notes', flex: 1, cellWrap: true}
                                ], //eo columns
                                autoLoad: true
                              });

                            },
                            failure: function(response, options) {}
                          });
                        },
                        collapse: function() {
                          console.log("Collapse function");
                          var me = this;
                          me.removeAll();
                        }
                      }//eo panel listeners
                    });//eo cont.add() 
                  }//eo for loop
                }, //eo success
                failure: function(response,  options) {
                  //HTTP GET request failure
                }//eo failure
              });//eo Ajax request
            } //eo click
          }//eo button listeners
```

Originally, the panels were dynamically generated along with their populated grids from the click event, which worked perfectly.  By wrapping the grid creation in a listener on the dynamically generated panel to create a load-as-needed, I can't get the expand or collapse listeners to trigger.

Searching around, one possible solution I haven't tried is to create a custom component and call it through its xtype rather than build everything in-line, which would let me define listeners there instead of nesting them in a function (this is better as well for readable and reusable code, but I'm just trying to get to the root of the issue for now).

Is there an issue with listeners on dynamically generated panels?  What is the reason that the event triggers for collapse and expand aren't firing?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I've just moved the panel in `container.add()` into its own component, and called it through xtype.  I am able to get the expand function to trigger, but I'm not sure how to get the component of the listener (I was only guessing with `var me=this; me.add()`).  Also, strangely, outer panels I was using as containers suddenly became collapsed and had headers, so I'll have to look into that as well.

Comment: Offtopic: I would recommend you to separate your listener functions from the view or at least write it under the items definition with usage of listenerScope. Also that store can be defined under the whole class or in different file and just called by name etc. Because it looks like a spaghetti code. Check this fiddle for the listeners https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1brb

Comment: Sure, I'll be sure to separate those; I've only just gotten started, so I wasn't quite sure how to set a store in a different file and pass different sets of data to it through the grid config, or how to properly use Listeners; I'm sure it's simpler than I'm thinking.  I see your listener functions firing correctly, is there a reason why my listeners aren't firing?  Do I need to use listenerScope?  I'll keep testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still have a few issues, but as my main question was about firing the listeners, I'll write the solution I reached.

The issue I had was getting listeners to fire in a dynamically generated element.  This led to nested listener functions, and I hadn't defined a scope.  I had tried pagep's solution of setting the defaultListenerScope, but for me personally I didn't see a change.

I instead wrapped the listener functions into their own functions and called then through the listener like this:

```
listeners: {
    expand: 'expandFunction',
    collapse: 'collapseFunction'
},//eo panel listeners

expandFunction: function() {
    //Do Ajax request and add grid to panel
},
collapseFunction: function() {
    //Remove all child elements from this panel
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
listeners: {
    expand: function() {
        //Do Ajax request and add grid to panel
    },
    collapse: function() {
        //Remove all child elements from this panel
    }
},//eo panel listeners
```

By wrapping the info this way, I was able (to a certain degree) to remove the nesting of listeners with generated elements.  I also created a custom component and placed these listeners with the component I was generating.  My only issue now is populating the generated element, since I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` when trying to reference the itemId of my component.

My final simplified code, which generates a collapsed panel on button-click and populates it with generated data when expanded, looks like this:

```
//View.js
    click: function (button, e, eOpts) {
              Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'data/Countries.json',
                success: function(response, options) {
                  var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).results;
                  var container = Ext.getCmp('panelContainer');
                  console.log(container);
                  container.removeAll();
                  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                  {
                    container.add({
                      xtype: 'customPanel',
                      title: data[i].country
                    });
                  }
                });

//customPanel.js
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.CustomPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.customPanel',

    xtype: 'panel',
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    listeners: {
        expand: 'expandFunction',
        collapse: 'collapseFunction'
    },//eo panel listeners

    expandFunction: function() {
        //Do Ajax request and add grid to panel
    },
    collapseFunction: function() {
        //Remove all child elements from this panel
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems that it's still somewhat finicky when I try to use it this way, so I'll do more testing to see what the root cause of the issue is.  The events still don't seem to trigger unless there is a child element in the panel, which is really strange.